# Room Database SQLite - What is the threshhold on updates? Trying to perform 100 updates in a loop

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I essentially have 100 rows that I need to update at once. Does SQLite have a threshhold on how many you can update per second? What happens if it were 500 rows?

I'm using a for loop that calls my Room Repo class to do the update.

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : itemsToUpdate.entrySet()) {
            int id = entry.getKey();
            String itemName = entry.getValue();
            viewModel.updateMenuItem(id, itemName);
}
```

```
public Single<Integer> updateMenuItem(int menuItemId, String menuItemName){
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> menuItemDao.updateMenuItem(menuItemId, menuItemName));
    }
```

```
@Query("UPDATE menu_table SET itemName = :itemName WHERE id = :id")
    int updateMenuItem(int id, String itemName);
```

If one of the updates failed, how would I handle that scenario?

Comment: Room supports [transactions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Transaction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does SQLite have a threshhold on how many you can update per second?

I don't believe there is a set threshold rather that the amount that could be undertaken would be dependent upon the available resources.

Rather, what can be a bottle neck is when looping without doing so in a transaction. A transaction is a unit of work that is then written to disk (the bottle neck). A single SQL statement is by default a transaction. So a loop of 500 statements will incur 500 writes to disk (expensive).

Enclosing the 500 statements in a single transaction result in far less disk activity and I believe that is what you want to utilise.

- *Beware of the @Transaction annotation this only places the statement being executed in a Transaction (and any underlying statements built such as when a query access @Relation's).*

For your situation would need to begin a transaction before starting the loop and to then end the transaction when the loop in completed.

As such you would want something along the lines of :-

```
your_RoomDatase.beginTransaction();
for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : itemsToUpdate.entrySet()) {
            int id = entry.getKey();
            String itemName = entry.getValue();
            counter = counter + viewModel.updateMenuItem(id, itemName);
}
your_RoomDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful(); //<<<<<<<<<<< IF YOU WANT (see below)
your_RoomDatabase.endTransaction();
```

> If one of the updates failed, how would I handle that scenario?

It depends upon what you mean by failed. If an ID didn't exist this wouldn't constitute a failure as far as SQlite is concerned just that nothing was updated and the int returned from the update would be 0.

If however the value were a foreign key and the value didn't exist and the onConflict strategy were not IGNORE then a Foreign Key conflict (exception) would be the result.

Exceptions should be rare. So assuming that by fail you mean not update AND you didn't want to ignore the update not working. Then you could count the number of times > 0 was returned (should be 1 per update if done by id). If this doesn't match the number attempted then you may wish to not set the transaction as successful then the transaction will be rolled back i.e. NO UPDATES AT ALL WILL BE APPLIED.

- Of course you could handle other desired outcomes between the extremes but then you'd probably want to maintain a an array/list of which id's worked or didn't work.

In short you would need to decide upon a policy of how you want to handle "failed updates".

You should also check out the other Transaction related methods at

- https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase#beginTransaction()